# Should I configure a watcher for less files in a meteor project

Tags: meteor, less, webstorm

I'm setting up a meteor project in Webstorm and so I added less, and converted my .css file to .less.

Webstorm sees that this is a .less file and prompts me to add a watcher.

Given that this is a meteor project, is it necessary to add the watcher or does Meteor take care of this?

Comment: I have included in my project the less compiler `meteor add less` so I am guessing that adding the watcher here is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use file watchers - if meteor less package is added, meteor takes care of compiling your .less files